# Multiple PHP versions in Wamp under Windows 7

Tags: php, wamp

I have already wamp under Windows 7 with php 5.3.8. I would like to install php5.3.19 and php.5.4.9 I have googled it and only instructions I found was this [article](http://absolutemg.com/2010/08/20/manually-install-php-on-wampserver/)

I tried those instructions and it didn't work for me. I see the extra versions when right clicking on the taskbar wamp icon but after that what ever I select php5.3.8 is running.

I have a phpinfo() script so to make sure.

Any instructions on how to do this? I don't want to uninstall php 5.3.8 as its my server's version.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes this process is rather easy. Go to their [downloads section](http://www.wampserver.com/en/#download-wrapper) of WampServer homepage. There you will see an Addons section, click the "Download PHP Addons" button. Select the versions you would like to download and run the installer.

**Updated (8/5/14):** Now they have it in their Sourceforge project under WampServer 2 - Extensions/PHP/ Here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/wampserver/files/WampServer%202%20-%20Extensions/PHP/

Comment: If you see the addons the highest version is 5.3.1

Comment: @spryno724, where is the addon link? I can't find it for three days. Yes I need to install 5.3.1

Comment: @Kannu Now they have it in their Sourceforge project under WampServer 2 - Extensions/PHP/ Here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/wampserver/files/WampServer%202%20-%20Extensions/PHP/

Comment: I did not find addons section there