# how to downgrade php 5.5 to 5.3 or using 5.5 as 5.3?

Tags: php

I have *Wamp Server* with **php 5.5** and i want to downgrade it to 5.3.
Is it possible with not delete **5.5** ?

Where can i find **php 5.3** version ?

Comment: why do you want to downgrade?

Comment: u can install install `XAMP` with php 5.3 version

Comment: This will answer your question, please search for your question before posting one. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25397219/how-to-downgrade-php-from-5-5-to-5-3

Comment: i believe in wampserver (http://www.wampserver.com/en/) you can install multiple php versions and switch between them

Comment: So where can I download PHP 5.3 for Wamp?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13634364/multiple-php-versions-in-wamp-under-windows-7

Comment: As @user2768665 said, possible duplicate of [How to downgrade php from 5.5 to 5.3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25397219/how-to-downgrade-php-from-5-5-to-5-3)