# magento 2 and laravel not support due to different php version

Tags: laravel, magento, php-7

I had a simple query but don't know how to work on it, I am working on two Different Project one is in Laravel 5.6 and other is in Magento 2.1. Now my problem comes when i am trying to install both on the same server because my Laravel support PHP 7.1 and i am using a theme Magento(Porto) which support 7.0.

I want to know how to install both on my server. I have already a built side of Laravel. I had to check some google it gives me multiple PHP version related help. but how to implement it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure which development server you are using at your local machine. However, you can have more than one `PHP version`.

You can switch between versions. Refer below.

[image]

Perhaps, this may help you.

[Multiple PHP versions in Wamp under Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13634364/multiple-php-versions-in-wamp-under-windows-7)

If you are using `Ubuntu` try below,

https://www.tecmint.com/install-different-php-versions-in-ubuntu/

Comment: no sir, m not working on local its Ubunto 16.04 . Linode server

Comment: @SohanSingh refer the other blog for ubuntu.

Comment: i had install php 7.1 and 7.0  on my server. but now problem .. how to switch php version according to website ..i have 2 website 1 supporting 7.1 and another one 7.0

Comment: @SohanSingh have you tried https://tecadmin.net/switch-between-multiple-php-version-on-ubuntu/ to switch PHP versions.